Pod memory heaping up for a spring boot microservice
I have a spring boot microservice with multiple RPCs. Recently the pod memory started heaping up slowly, ultimately leading to high memory usage and OOM error.
I tried taking heapdump and analysing to find the issue, but could not find anything conclusive. Also the heap dump size is overall constant.
